Touchpad Lagging in Ubuntu 22.04 (Dell XPS 15 2023 version)
My touchpad is not very responsive in my brand new Dell XPS 15 which is double booted with Ubuntu 22.04. My finger movements on the touchpad often result in no movement at all in the cursor, as if commands aren't being properly received by the OS. This forces me to move my fingers multiple times before the cursor finally moves, which is annoying.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Many thanks if so!
I have tried using both libinput and synaptics drivers for my touchpad but the issue persists. I don't have multiple drivers for my touchpad running at once.
